# Given a set of whole numbers. Find out the number of ways to select a subset of that set such that--

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Given a set $A = \{a_1, a_2 ... a_n\}\subset \mathbb{N}_0 =\{0, 1, 2 ....\}$.

Find the number of subsets $S \subseteq A$, such that:

$\bullet \;\; 2 \leq |S| \leq n$

$\bullet\;\;$  if $s_i, s_j \in S \implies |s_i - s_j|\geq  k, k \in \mathbb{N},  k <n $

Comment: $A= \left\{ x: x \in W \right\}$, does this mean $A=W$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

For special kind of sets $A$, any subset $S\subset A$ will have the property.  We can use the concept of subgroups and cosets in the group **Z**.

Fix a $k$ and consider the subgroup $k$**Z**. Let $A$ be any subset of any of the coset of $k\mathbf{Z}$. Two distinct elements of a coset differ at least by $k$.

Example $k=10$. Take the set $A$ by picking elements from a single coset , say, $A= ${8,28,88, 98,338, 1008}$. Any two numbers differ by 8 here.

In general for a general set $A$ find an arithmetic progression $P$  that has large intersection with $A$. If the common difference of $P$ is $d$ then in $A\subset P$ any two elements will differ by at least $d$.

(One can replace $P$ by any subsequence of an arithmetic progression).

Comment: A is not any special set. It is general. Is there any way to calculate for a general set? If we try to calculate an Arithmetic progression, we might miss some elements of A. We need to find the number of all the possible subsets such that they satisfy the given condition.

Comment: Towards the end of my answer I have given one suggestion how to handle a general set: e.g.$\{7,12,13,14,19,22,23,29,35,37,40,44,52,58\}$. The subset $\{7,12,22,37,52\}$ is contained in the A.P.  $7,12,17,22,\ldots$ and so difference 5 is possible for this subset.